# Data not appear in datatables

Tags: json, datatables

I have data json like this

```
[{
    "Lembar_BPJS_Kesehatan": "2",
    "Total_BPJS_Kesehatan": "56000",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT": "5",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT": "398300",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_UMBU_KAB__NIAS": "1",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTA_UMBU_KAB__NIAS": "23089",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR": "319",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR": "20434870",
    "Lembar_PLN_Postpaid": "103",
    "Total_PLN_Postpaid": "10272775",
    "Lembar_Pulsa_Listrik": "30",
    "Total_Pulsa_Listrik": "1905000",
    "Lembar_Telkom": "4",
    "Total_Telkom": "1716000",
    "tgl_dari": "2018-04-20",
    "tgl_sampai": "2018-04-20"
}]
```

I want to display on datatables with my code, this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                var dataku = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url+'laporan/load_trx_per_tgl_bukopin',
                    dataType: 'json', 
                    success: function(data){
                        dataku = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));;
                        console.log(dataku);                            
                }
                });

                $('#tabelTransaksiPerTglBukopin').DataTable( {
                    'dom': 'Zlfrtip',
                    'scrollX': true,
                    'data': dataku
                });
            });
```

but, not able to display in my data tables. This my view :

[image: test]

Comment: You can just put your datatables code in your `AJAX success`.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dataku = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url+'laporan/load_trx_per_tgl_bukopin',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data){
      dataku = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));;
      console.log(dataku);
      $('#tabelTransaksiPerTglBukopin').DataTable( {
        'dom': 'Zlfrtip',
        'scrollX': true,
        'data': dataku
      });  
      }
    });      
 });
```

ajax stand for asynchronous javascript and xml. that's mean the data you fetch need time untill it's ready to be use. 
if you move your datatable into the success callback, that make sure the `dataku` is available when you use it.

hope it help

Comment: @HendriAm can you `console.log(data)`

Comment: @SachiTekina yes, so

Comment: dont forget to refresh with ctrl+f5 in chrome for hard reload

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to directly use AJAX as your data source in Datatables:

```
$('#tabelTransaksiPerTglBukopin').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: base_url + 'laporan/load_trx_per_tgl_bukopin',
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  'dom': 'Zlfrtip',
  'scrollX': true,
  'columns': [{
      "data": "Lembar_BPJS_Kesehatan"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_BPJS_Kesehatan"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_UMBU_KAB__NIAS"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_PLN_Postpaid"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_PLN_Postpaid"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_Pulsa_Listrik"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_Pulsa_Listrik"
    },
    {
      "data": "Lembar_Telkom"
    },
    {
      "data": "Total_Telkom"
    },
    {
      "data": "tgl_dari"
    },
    {
      "data": "tgl_sampai"
    }
  ]
});
```

Given that the JSON result of your AJAX has this format:

```
[{
    "Lembar_BPJS_Kesehatan": "2",
    "Total_BPJS_Kesehatan": "56000",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT": "5",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTA_BULIAN_TB_TINGGI_SUMUT": "398300",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTA_UMBU_KAB__NIAS": "1",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTA_UMBU_KAB__NIAS": "23089",
    "Lembar_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR": "319",
    "Total_PDAM_TIRTAULI_KOTA_PEMATANGSIANTAR": "20434870",
    "Lembar_PLN_Postpaid": "103",
    "Total_PLN_Postpaid": "10272775",
    "Lembar_Pulsa_Listrik": "30",
    "Total_Pulsa_Listrik": "1905000",
    "Lembar_Telkom": "4",
    "Total_Telkom": "1716000",
    "tgl_dari": "2018-04-20",
    "tgl_sampai": "2018-04-20"
}]
```

Comment: the problem, if data json is dynamic, how to put it ?

Comment: @HendriAm You mean different structure and length?

Comment: You should specify that in your question.